# Feed the goal to Prolog from commandline

Tags: compilation, prolog, arguments

The title says it all. I want to compile a program (say with gplc). Then pass an input file to it. The program will read the file, does some computation and writes the output to another file. In C, I would do something like this:

```
gcc -o prog prog.c
./prog input.txt output.txt
```

Can I do the same in Prolog? If it is, how can I read input arguments from commandline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the implementation you are using, but there is a builtin called `current_prolog_flag/2` (read the manual) that can be called like this to access the command line arguments passed to a program:

```
...
current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
...
```

`Argv` will be unified with a list of atoms representing the command line arguments.

To tell Prolog which goal to run, again, consult the manual of the implementation you are using:

http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/html_node/gprolog009.html#sec18

Comment: Do note that `argv` is not a standard flag, however, and there are differences between Prolog systems regarding this flag in particular and this functionality in general. Be sure to consult the documentation of the Prolog system you're using for details.